Realm Swift many-to-many linking objects not persisting when I restart app
I have an app that retrieves iOS contacts from the UI and then creates "ProductionContact" objects from them. My goal is to assign these contacts to numerous existing shoots and productions. Everything seems to work fine the first go around.
Here are the object models:
class Production: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id: String = NSUUID().uuidString
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    
    // each production can have many shoots
    let shoots = List<Shoot>()

    // each Production can have many ProductionContacts
    var productionContacts = List<ProductionContact>()

}

class Shoot: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id: String = NSUUID().uuidString
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    // each shoot has only one production
    @objc dynamic var production: Production?
    var productions = LinkingObjects(fromType: Production.self, property: "shoots")

    // each shoot can have many ProductionContacts
    var productionContacts = List<ProductionContact>()

}

class ProductionContact: Object {
    
    @objc dynamic var id: String = NSUUID().uuidString

    // inverse of List<ProductionContact>() relationship in Shoot object
    var shoots = LinkingObjects(fromType: Shoot.self, property: "productionContacts")

    // inverse of List<ProductionContact>() relationship in Production object
    var productions = LinkingObjects(fromType: Production.self, property: "productionContacts")

    @objc dynamic var firstName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var lastName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var phone: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var email: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var url: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var socialPlatform: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var socialHandle: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var IMDbUrl: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var notes: String = ""

}

When I write these new objects to the list property "productionContacts" in the existing Shoot and Production objects, realm seems to write the data fine. The list property "productionContacts" in both the Shoot and Production objects contains the new ProductionContact objects. I can navigate through the app and the data is retained.
Here are the functions that I'm using:
func fetchContactImageUrls(from contacts: [CNContact], completion: @escaping(Bool?) -> Void) {
    
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    for contact in contacts {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        if contact.imageDataAvailable, let imageData = contact.imageData, let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            // image found, save to camera roll and update image url
            let identifier = contact.identifier
            ImageManager.instance.createAlbum(image: image) { localID in
                
                guard let localID = localID else { return }
                print(localID)
                self.imageUrls[identifier] = localID
                dispatchGroup.leave()
                
            }
        } else {
            // no image found
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
        print("Fetched image urls if there were any")
        if self.imageUrls.count > 0 {
            completion(true)
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }
    })
    
}

func createProductionContactsFromiOSContacts(_ contacts: [CNContact]) -> [ProductionContact] {
    
    var localPCs = [ProductionContact]()
    
    contacts.forEach({
        
        let pC = ProductionContact()
        pC.iOSContactIDKey = $0.identifier
        pC.firstName = $0.givenName.isEmpty ? "No First Name" : $0.givenName
        pC.lastName = $0.familyName.isEmpty ? "No Last Name" : $0.familyName
        pC.title = $0.jobTitle.isEmpty ? "No Job Title" : $0.jobTitle
        pC.email = ($0.emailAddresses.first?.value as? String) ?? ""
        pC.phone = ($0.phoneNumbers.first?.value as? CNPhoneNumber)?.stringValue ?? ""
        pC.socialHandle = ($0.socialProfiles.first?.value as? CNSocialProfile)?.username ?? ""
        pC.socialPlatform = ($0.socialProfiles.first?.label as? String) ?? ""
      
        pC.image = imageUrls[$0.identifier] ?? ""
        
        
        localPCs.append(pC)
        
    })
    print("created \(localPCs.count) Production Contacts from iOS contacts")
    
    return localPCs
    
}

func addContactsToRealm(_ contacts: [CNContact]) {
    
    fetchContactImageUrls(from: contacts) { listHasImages in
        
        guard let listHasImages = listHasImages else { return }
        self.addPCsToRealm()
        
    }
    
}

func addPCsToRealm() {
    
    do {
        try realm.write {
            
            self.pCs = self.createProductionContactsFromiOSContacts(contacts)
            realm.add(self.pCs)
            
            guard let shoot = self.selectedShoot else { return }
            guard let production = shoot.production else { return }
            
            shoot.productionContacts.append(objectsIn: self.pCs)
            production.productionContacts.append(objectsIn: self.pCs)
            
        }
    } catch {
        print("error adding contact to production or shoot. Not sure which tho.")
    }
    
    guard let sid = id else { return }
    self.reloadOnSet(id: sid)
    
}

func contactPicker(didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {
        
        self.contacts.append(contentsOf: contacts)
        self.addContactsToRealm(contacts)
        
}

The problem is, when I restart the app and list the Production Contacts, all the properties and objects are intact--Except for the list property "productionContacts" within the Shoot and Production objects. It's empty, and the relationships between them are lost. I have scoured my code and there is no other place where I change the list property "productionContacts" in either the Shoot or Production objects.
I feel like I don't fully understand how RealmSwift handles these linking object properties in a many-to-many relationship.
Why is it not persisting these list properties after the app restarts?

Two things. First thing is not an error but something to be aware of: Realm is pretty smart; when an unmanaged object is added to a managed objects List property, it will also be written to Realm; you don't need to do it twice e.g. this realm.add(self.pCs) is not needed. The issue may involve ignoring errors. See this line of code? guard let shoot = self.selectedShoot else { return } if selectedShoot is nil, the code will silently fail and you'd never know about it - and that would cause the Lists to never be appended. Update to else { print("selected shoot was nil")  return }.

Ah ok thanks for the advice re: no need to do a realm.add().
guard let shoot = self.selectedShoot else { return } is not failing, I've put a print statement there like you suggested, and it's never nil.
I'm starting to think that maybe I can't pass the ProductionContact object itself into both the Production and Shoot objects as it may somehow create a recursive definition. (each Production can have many Shoots, if both Productions and Shoots have ProductionContacts) I'll try to store the ProductionContact.id's in a List instead and see if that changes anything.

somehow create a recursive definition nope, not how it works. Relationships are by reference and multiple objects and refer to the same objects in a List. Storing id's as a string is not a relationship and an inverse relationship will not be automatically created (which is what you want). Also, please use Swift in your objects at this point; instead of @objc dynamic var id: String = NSUUID().uuidString user @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId

For future readers: the above code uses Realm SDK 10.7.7 from June 2021. List and Linking objects should be defined as let not var. From the docs - LinkingObjects can only be used as a property on Object models. Properties of this type must be declared as let
and cannot be dynamic.

Edit: As more info was provided, the question is based on Realm SDK 10.7.7 From June 2021. The List and LinkingObjects are not correctly defined - they must be 'let' not 'var'. From the Docs

LinkingObjects can only be used as a property on Object models.
Properties of this type must be declared as let and cannot be dynamic.

Original Answer which still somewhat applies:
There are a number of things going wrong so let me try to address all at once:
Here's some of the issues: There are ObjC intermixed with Swift constructs, variables not declared correctly (ObjC List must be a let), and the ObjC implementation is for an old SDK and the inverse relationships do not have the correct syntax. To fix, update the objects to be Swift:
This
class Production: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = NSUUID().uuidString
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    let shoots = List<Shoot>() //note this is a let
    var productionContacts = List<ProductionContact>() //note this is a **var**
}

should be
class Production: Object {
   @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
   @Persisted var shoots = RealmSwift.List<Shoot>()
   @Persisted var productionContacts = RealmSwift.List<ProductionContact>()
}

and then an inverse relationship example would be:
class ProductionContact: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted(originProperty: "productionContacts") var productions: LinkingObjects<Production>
    @Persisted(originProperty: "productionContacts") var shoots: LinkingObjects<Shoot>

I'll leave it to you to update the Shoot class.
That should take care of it.

I am getting the compiler error: Unknown attribute 'Persisted'.
Is that b/c I'm running Swift 4? I'm not 100% sure my pod dependencies will be able to run on Swift 5, hence I've delayed the upgrade.

@MischkaTheBear Persisted has been around for years and when Realm was migrated to support Swift. Swift 4 is fine but what version of the Realm SDK are you using? It's possible your podfile needs to updated as well.

Weird. Realm Swift version is 10.7.7. Can't find any info anywhere about the compiler error: Unknown attribute 'Persisted'. I updated my install of Cocoapods to 1.15.2 and did a pod update before this, and the compiler still protests.

@MischkaTheBear 10.7.7? That's from June 2021. I don't think @Persisted was around yet so objects were declared using the ObjC Syntax at that time @objc dynamic var name = "" so that would explain it. I suggest it's time to update. Also, with that version , LinkingObjects and List must be let not var

I see. Thanks for all your help this far. I really appreciate it. I have a pod dependency IceCream which syncs Realm Database with CloudKit, so when I try to update to RealmSwift to latest version RealmSwift (~> 10.52.0), cocoapods complains "IceCream (~> 2.0.4) was resolved to 2.0.4, which depends on RealmSwift (< 10.8.0)". Any suggestions for pods or other methods to sync Realm Database with CloudKit as alternative to IceCream so I can update RealmSwift properly? All I found depend on RealmSwift v 10.8.0 or lower. @Persisted was introduced in RealmSwift 10.10.0 it looks like.

Note that IceCream appears to be an unmaintained project at this point so it may not work properly.
